# Pandas loop a dataframe and compare all rows with other DF rows and assign a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DF:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3, 2, 5, 1, 6], 'B': [4, 6, 5, 8, 2], 'C': [4, 8, 3, 8, 0], 'D':[1, 4, 2, 8, 7], 'zebra': [5, 7, 2, 4, 8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [7, 3, 5, 1, 8], 'D':[4, 5, 8, 2, 3] })


print(df1)
print(df2)

   A  B  C  D    zebra
0  3  4  4  1      5
1  2  8  8  5      7
2  5  5  3  2      2
3  1  6  8  5      4
4  6  2  0  7      8
   B  D
0  7  4
1  3  5
2  5  8
3  8  5
4  8  3
```

This is a simple example, in real df1 is with 1000k+ rows and 10+ columns, df2 is with only 24 rows and fewer columns as well. I would like to loop all rows in df2 and to compare those specific rows (for example column 'B' and 'D') from df2 with same column names in df1 and if row values match (if value in column B and column D in df2 match same values in same columns but in df1) to assign corresponding zebra value in that row to the same row in df2 creating new column zebra and assigning that value. If no matching found to assign 0s or NaN's.

```
   B  D  zebra
0  7  4  nan
1  3  5  nan
2  5  8  nan
3  8  5  7
4  8  3  nan
```

From example, only row index 3 in df2 matched values 'B': 8 and 'D':5 with a row with index 2 from df1 (NOTE: row index should not be important in comparisons) and assign corresponding row value 7 from column 'zebra' to df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A merge would do

```
df2.merge(df1[['B', 'D', 'zebra']], on = ['B', 'D'], how = 'left')

    B   D   zebra
0   7   4   NaN
1   3   5   NaN
2   5   8   NaN
3   8   5   7.0
4   8   3   NaN
```

Comment: almost mate, it's creating more rows than 24 original rows in d2. Also, there are other columns in df2 as df1 just not mention it to confuse more but need to be accurate as well(not compare them, however). In df1 are 14k rows, there may be more than 1 combination with same values. After df2.merge are created 14k rows.

Comment: When you merge on [B, D], it will compare only those 2 columns so you don't have to worry about more columns present in df2. I am surprised by the number of rows though. How many rows are you getting in df2?